# Hybris Solr failed to load core

Tags: solr, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to hybris and trying to load my apparel store data. Whenever I perform an ant initialize, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core mProduct: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "string": Error loading class 'de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.similarity.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory'. Schema file is E:\hybris\config\solr\instances\default\configsets\default\conf\schema.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:80)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:725)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:701)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:629)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:214)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:675)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:443)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "string": Error loading class 'de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.similarity.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory'. Schema file is E:\hybris\config\solr\instances\default\configsets\default\conf\schema.xml
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:175)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:75)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "string": Error loading class 'de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.similarity.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory'
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:489)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.similarity.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:491)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:560)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:525)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSimilarity(IndexSchema.java:977)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:109)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:52)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:152)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.similarity.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:475)
    ... 42 more
```

This is how my localextensions.xml looks like:

```
<hybrisconfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources/schemas/extensions.xsd">
    <extensions>
        <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />
        <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom" />


        <!-- ext-platform -->
        <extension name="admincockpit" />
        <extension name="backoffice" />
        <extension name="cockpit" />
        <extension name="hmc" />
        <extension name="mcc" />
        <extension name="platformhmc" />
        <extension name="amazoncloud" />

        <!-- ext-commerce -->
        <extension name="btg" />
        <extension name="btgcockpit" />
        <extension name="commercesearch" />
        <extension name="commercesearchbackoffice" />
        <extension name="commercesearchhmc" />
        <extension name="commerceservices" />
        <extension name="basecommerce" />
        <extension name="payment" />
        <extension name="promotions" />
        <extension name="voucher" />
        <extension name="customerreview" />
        <extension name="ticketsystem" />
        <extension name="solrfacetsearch" />
        <extension name="solrfacetsearchhmc" />
        <extension name="wishlist" />
        <extension name="commercefacades" />

        <!-- ext-data -->
        <extension name="commercesearchsampledata" />
        <extension name="mediaconversion" />

        <!-- ext-content -->
        <extension name="productcockpit" />
        <extension name="cms2" />
        <extension name="cms2lib" />
        <extension name="cmscockpit" />
        <extension name="mobileoptionals" />
        <extension name="mobileservices" />
        <extension name="cscockpit" />
        <extension name="instore" />

        <!-- ext-addon -->
        <extension name="addonsupport" />

        <!-- ext-accelerator -->
        <extension name="acceleratorservices" />
        <extension name="acceleratorfacades" />
        <extension name="acceleratorcms" />
        <extension name="acceleratorstorefrontcommons" />



       <!-- Solr server extension -->
      <extension name="solrserver"/>

       <!--  Lucene-search extension for backoffice -->
       <extension name="lucenesearch"/>

       <extension name='warehousingbackoffice' />



       <extension name='paymentgatewaymockaddon' />

       <!-- Adding extensions for backoffice -->
       <!--  add them at the end of every backoffice extension -->
       <extension name="platformbackoffice"/>
       <extension name="mediaconversionbackoffice"/>

       <!-- unbxd integration -->
       <extension name="unbxd"/>

    </extensions>
</hybrisconfig>
```

Is there anyway I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: which hybris version are you working on? could you add your localextensions.xml?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian , I am working on Hybris 5.7 and updated my post with localextensions.xml content.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the jar file that contains FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory is not found when core is loaded. It should be either in the lib directory or referenced in **solrconfig.xml**. Perhaps the location the library is put into is different from where your Solr/core is.

Answer (score 0):

The jar library mentioned by @Alexandre is `hybriscomponents.5.5.1.0.jar` (or the newer one: `solr-hybris-components-7.4.3.jar`). The package of class `FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory` has changed with the version of the JAR file.

All you need to do is change all references from:
`de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.ysolr.similarity.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory`

into:

`de.hybris.platform.lucene.search.similarities.FixedTFIDFSimilarityFactory`

inside all your `schema*.xml` files.